# PHP PDO shows "no value"

Tags: apache, pdo, php

I've seen many questions describing this issue but none tackling the solution.

Last night I updated PHP from 5.3.2 to 5.4.6 and all of the sudden PDO started acting strange and showing that no drivers were available.

- I have necessary DLL (php_pdo_mysql.dll) in `ext` directory
- In `php.ini` both PDO and database-specific extension are enabled
- The following code acts differently when executed from terminal/cmd and from browser:

  `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());`

  in terminal/cmd it shows appropriate driver list while in browser shows empty array.

All this led me to believe that something was not quite right with Apache installation (which is still at `2.2`). I've installed version `2.4` just to be sure but nothing has changed.

When called, `phpinfo()` shows correct `php.ini` path but is there anything else that could affect proper PDO loading?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show some code demonstrating the problem

Comment: What OS are you using? How did you perform the PHP upgrade?

Comment: In phpinfo, does it show PDO information section?

Comment: It looks like you are on ubuntu or similar OS. Check for the php.ini in `/etc/php5/`. There should be `apache2` and `cli` folders containing different ini files for command line and apache. Probably the apache one been replaced with default upon upgrade.

Comment: Actually there is no code at all since I'm stuck at very beginning. PHP is running under `Win7 x64` and while it shows `PDO` section it says 'no value'. However, section 'pdo_mysql' is not present. Zysoft, since this is no ubuntu, by "update" I meant installing it in parallel. I checked my PHP installation for those directories but none of them were present...

Comment: @jperovic Try checking the phpinfo output for terminal and web and compare the php.ini paths.

Comment: @zysoft I checked the php.ini path and in both cases it points to the same file :-/

Comment: @jperovic It looks strange. As long as you installed it in parallel, I can guess you have your 5.3.2 in PATH which has precedence and that's why it works from terminal. It is also possible that extensions buit for 5.3 don't work with 5.4. Enable startup errors to check if this is true.

Comment: @zysoft When I do `php -v` in terminal it shows `PHP 5.4.6-Win64 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2012 16:20:17)`. This is really strange issue and you could be right about extension incompatibility. I'm going to give it a try with some older version - say 5.4.0 or something like that...